# Customized Biblatex References

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[authordate,bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,natbib,giveninits=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{grossmanhart80,
    author  = {Sanford Grossman and Oliver Hart},
    title   = {Takeover Bids, The Free-Rider Problem, and the Theory of the Corporation},
    journal = {The Bell Journal of Economics},
    year    = {1980},
    volume  = {11},
    number  = {1},
    pages   = {42--64}
}

@book{hilliergrinblatttitman11,
    author      ={David Hillier and Mark Grinblatt and Sheridan Titman},
    title       ={Financial Markets and Corporate Strategy},
    publisher   ={McGraw-Hill},
    year        ={2011},
    edition     ={Second Edition}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} % remove quotation marks from articles
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\linespread{1.5}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

which produces this output:

[image: references]

I have two questions: **1** how can I add parentheses to the year for both the article and the book, and **2** how do I make the volume of the article (11) in italic without making the number (1) in italic as well?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complicated styles like `biblatex-chicago` can be a pain to modify, especially if they implement a comprehensive style guide such as the CMS or APA style.

For issue number one we can redefine the macro `cmsbibyear` to add `\printtext{\bibopenparen}` and `\printtext{\bibcloseparen}`. The code did not allow for the more idiomatic `\printtext[parens]{...}`, so we had to go for this kludge.

Issue two is easily and elegantly solved by redefining the `jourvol` field format.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authordate,bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,natbib,giveninits=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\renewbibmacro*{cmsbibyear}{%
  \printtext{\bibopenparen}%
  \iftoggle{cms@origlabel}%
    {\usebibmacro{origyear+labelyear}}%
    {\iftoggle{cms@bothlabelnew}%
       {\usebibmacro{bothyear+oldstyle}}%
       {\iftoggle{cms@bothlabelold}%
          {\usebibmacro{bothyear+oldstyle}}%
          {\usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}}}}%
  \ifcsdef{@cms@tempdate}%
    {\toggletrue{\@cms@tempdate}}%
    {}%
  \printtext{\bibcloseparen}}%


\DeclareFieldFormat{jourvol}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{grossmanhart80,
    author  = {Sanford Grossman and Oliver Hart},
    title   = {Takeover Bids, The Free-Rider Problem, and the Theory of the Corporation},
    journal = {The Bell Journal of Economics},
    year    = {1980},
    volume  = {11},
    number  = {1},
    pages   = {42--64}
}

@book{hilliergrinblatttitman11,
    author      ={David Hillier and Mark Grinblatt and Sheridan Titman},
    title       ={Financial Markets and Corporate Strategy},
    publisher   ={McGraw-Hill},
    year        ={2011},
    edition     ={Second Edition}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Grossman, S., and O. Hart. (1980). Takeover Bids, The Free-Rider Problem, and the Theory of the Corporation. *The Bell Journal of Economics* **11** (1): 42–64. Hillier, D., M. Grinblatt, and S. Titman. (2011). *Financial Markets and Corporate Strategy.* Second Edition. McGraw-Hill.]

Comment: Thank you very much. Although my question was to make the journal volume in _italic_, it seems to be easily changed with `\DeclareFieldFormat{jourvol}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}`. Have a nice day.